# How to return a single value built from values stored in multiple records?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am an application developer unfortunately put in the position of needing to write (/update) the SQL statement in order to return data for the application. My experience with SQL is limited, so would appreciate any help.

We have a Oracle Database 11g (11.2.0.4.0)

## Example Tables

I've created the following example which replicates our set-up. It consists of:

- A main table which contains records of trips around different cities. (*MAIN_TRIP_TABLE*)
- Various additional tables which contain additional properties linked to these trips via INNER JOINs. (*ADDITIONAL_TABLE*)
- A separate table showing the steps taken along the journey (ie. interim locations visited). A value of STEP_NUM = 1 is always the final destination, and thus there is always at least 1 record in this table per trip in the main table. If there were any interim stops made of the journey they are listed in this table as separate records with STEP_NUM iterating upwards. (*JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE*)

*MAIN_TRIP_TABLE*

```
RECORD_ID | PROP_1 | PROP_2 | FINAL_DEST | ...
-------------------------------------------------
10001     | A      | 1      | London     | ...
10002     | A      | 0      | Reading    | ...
10003     | B      | 1      | Leeds      | ...
10004     | B      | 0      | York       | ...
```

*ADDITIONAL_TABLE*

```
RECORD_ID | PROP_3 | ...
------------------------
10001     | X      | ...
10002     | Y      | ...
10003     | Y      | ...
10004     | X      | ...
```

*JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE*

```
RECORD_ID | STEP_NUM | LOCATION | ...
--------------------------------------
10001     | 1        | London   | ...
10002     | 1        | Reading  | ...
10002     | 2        | Bath     | ...
10003     | 1        | Leeds    | ...
10003     | 2        | York     | ...
10003     | 3        | Bristol  | ...
10004     | 1        | York     | ...
10004     | 2        | Cardiff  | ...
10004     | 3        | Oxford   | ...
10004     | 4        | London   | ...
```

## Issue

I want to retrieve something that looks like:

```
SELECT
  MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID
, MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.PROP_1
, MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.PROP_2
, ADDITIONAL_TABLE.PROP_3
, <Concatenation/Array of JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE> as "InterimStops"
FROM MAIN_TRIP_TABLE
INNER JOIN ADDITIONAL_TABLE ON MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID = ADDITIONAL_TABLE.RECORD_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE ON MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID = JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.RECORD_ID
```

Where the "InterimStops" value above is some sort of concatenation of any and all values in found in the JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE, for that particular RECORD_ID, in order of increasing STEP_NUM, with some sort of deliminator. (eg for '10001' I would want just *"London"*, and for '10004' I would want *"York,Cardiff,Oxford,London"*).

If I get something like this, I can then separate these out to an JSON array, within the application I'm developing.

Note: The actual SQL SELECT query is already significantly more complex with other fields and tables, so changing the query away from 1 SELECT query (ie. instead using multiple queries), is something I'd like to avoid unless absolutely necessary.

## Things I've tried

After some Googling, I started to build a SQL statement using *LISTAGG*, and to begin with it looked promising:

```
SELECT
  MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID
, LISTAGG(JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.LOCATION, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.STEP_NUMBER) "InterimStops"
FROM MAIN_TRIP_TABLE
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE ON MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID = JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.RECORD_ID
GROUP BY MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID
```

This returned exactly the sort of value I was looking for, but this failed as soon as I tried to bring back in the other values from both the main table and additional tables (eg: *MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.PROP_1, MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.PROP_2, ADDITIONAL_TABLE.PROP_3*). This gave me a "*ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression*" error.

I then tried to get this data via a subquery but struggled to get anything working.

Any help, insight, or pointing in the right direct, would be very much appreciated.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do this with a subquery so you don't have to group the data on the joined set of columns (as you allready tried):

```
SELECT MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID
     , (SELECT LISTAGG(JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.LOCATION, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.STEP_NUMBER) 
          FROM JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE
         WHERE JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.RECORD_ID = MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID) "InterimStops"
FROM MAIN_TRIP_TABLE
```

The other possibility is to `LEFT JOIN` the grouped data:

```
SELECT MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID
     , JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE."InterimStops"
  FROM MAIN_TRIP_TABLE
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT RECORD_ID
                  , LISTAGG(LOCATION, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STEP_NUMBER) "InterimStops"
               FROM JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE
              GROUP BY RECORD_ID) JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE
    ON JOURNEY_STEPS_TABLE.RECORD_ID = MAIN_TRIP_TABLE.RECORD_ID
```